# js function not working in aspx (form validation)

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to write a form in aspx page includes veification in the submit button.Even if i run debugger clicking the submit doesn't perfom the Js code (or maybe there is a problem in syntax that i dont' know what is it). Can anyone help me find the mistake (either synax of script or something in the html)? thanks alot:)
the code of default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>טופס הרשמה</title>
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/javascript" href="style.css" />
<script>
    var FinalMsg = "";
    function VerifyForm() {
        VerUser();
        VerPasses();
        VerGen();
        alert(FinalMsg);
    }        
    function VerUser(){
        var vus = document.getElementById("username").value;
        if(vus.length=0)
        {
            FinalMsg+="type username";
        }
    }
    function VerPasses(){
        var vpasfir = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
        var vpassec = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
        if(vpasfir.length=0)
        {
            FinalMsg+="type password";
        }
        if(vpassec.length=0)
        {
            FinalMsg+="type the secondary pass";
        }
        if (vpasfir.value != vpassec.value) 
        {
            FinalMsg+="passs aren't match";
        }
    }         
    function VerGen() {
        var vgen1 = document.getElementById("male").value;
        var vgen2 = document.getElementById("female").value;
        var vgen3 = document.getElementById("other").value;
        if ((vgen1.checked==false)&&(vgen2.checked==false)&&(vgen3.checked==false&&)){
            FinalMsg += "haven;t chosen gender";
        }
    }

</script>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">
<center>   <img src="Title.gif" width="500px"/></center> 
<form id="FormAboutYou" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="validateForm()">
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="field">שם משתמש</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field">סיסמה</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass1" id="pass1"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="field">סיסמה בשנית</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pass2" id="pass2"/></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="field">כתובת דוא"ל</td>
        <td><input type="email" name="email" id="email"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field">מזונות מועדפים</td>
        <td  Class="ChooseFrom">
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Choclate" id="choc" /> שוקולד <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Fries" id="fries"/> צ'יפס <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Tomatoes and other vegetables" id="veg"/> ירקות ופירות <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Pasta" id="pasta"/> פסטה <br />
            <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Cheese" id="che"/>גבינה <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td class="field">מגדר</td>

       <td class="ChooseFrom">
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" id="male"/> זכר <br />
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" id="femle"/> נקבה <br />
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Unde" id="other"/> עדיין לא החלטתי/יש לי בעיה עם שדות בינארים <br />

        </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="field">living in</td>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="TelAviv" id="ny">new york</option>
                <option value="PetaTikwa" id="rome">rome</option>
                <option value="QiryatOno" id="Paris">Paris</option>
                <option value="RamgatGan" id="lv">Las Vegas</option>
                <option value="Haifa" id="ln">London</option>
                <option value="Qraiot" id="bt">Bairut</option>
                <option value="Bash" id="bej">Beijing</option>
                <option value="Eilat" id="tk">Tokyo</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="הזן נתוניך על פני המים" onsubmit="VerifyForm();"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<hr />
<br /><br /><br /><br />  
<br /><br /><br /><br />
</body>
</html>
```

thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea could be to take `onsubmit()` out of the form tag.

then for your button change the `onSubmit` to `onclick='return verifyForm();`

In your `verifyForm()` method you need to return either `true` or `false`; if false, the form won't submit.

So, something like this at the end of your verifyForm()

```
if (FinalMsg == ""){
    return true;
  }else{
   return false;
 }
```

Comment: the practitioner wants us not to use "reutnr" but to make a final alert pops up with all errors in the page. thanks anyway:) does anybody have other suggestions?

Comment: you can show the alert, though you need to prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: how can i return both alert and false value?

Comment: show the alert first. then when the user clicks 'OK' the JS will then continue to run, returning the false.